# With the Python httplib "HTTPConnection" object, how do you send a header without a value?

Tags: python, http, httplib

I have the following code but httplib still treats the header 'emptyheader' as key:value pair.

```
h = httplib.HTTPConnection("somewhere:5000")
headers = {}
headers['emptyheader'] = None
h.request('POST', '/somewhere', '', headers)
```

How do I send the sane request but with a valueless header 'emptyheader'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do it using httplib. 'headers' parameter must be a dictionary. httplib then constructs headers as colon-separated name-value pairs.

And I think requests module does the same thing.

So, as an option, try curl:

```
subprocess.call(['curl', '-i', '-H', '"emptyheader"', '"http://somewhere:5000/somewhere"'])
```

But, I'm not sure why do you need it: http headers are key:value pairs by design.

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me.
(To many nested quotes/no header is sent at all)

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid doing it this way but it looks like I may have to.

Answer (score 1):

Set the header value to `''`:

```
headers['emptyheader'] = ''
```

would output:

```
emptyheader: \r\n
```

which is conform with the [HTTP specification for message headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2).

Comment: httplib still treats the header as having a value when formatting the request.

Comment: @Will: It is *not* clear what output you are expecting, and how that compares to what you are seeing.